# How to pass multiple arguments in a command to execute an exe on remote linux machine using C/C++ and SSH

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ssh, command-line-arguments

I have successfully executed my exe on local machine using command
"./executable agr1 arg2 arg3 arg4" 
Then it shows value of  argument count to 5.
But when I wanted to do this same from a remote linux machine (system2) then I opened up SSH channel using libssh in QT creator then I did following:

1. QString str = "/root/executable arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4";
2. rc = channel_request_exec(channel, str);

Then the exe executed but it showed argument count to 1. Means arguments didn't passed correctly. What is the correct way of doing this ??

Comment: Try to print the passed string in the executable, channel_request_exec executes the command as shell command.

Comment: I printed using for(int i = 0; i <argc ; i++) { printf("℅s", argv[i]); } . It prints "root/executable" only.

Comment: Is that the EXACT code you are running? Or are you, for example, building the string `str` by code (that is possibly buggy)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of search on Google and Stackoverflow ( and it's variant) I found answer to above problem and that was not exactly a formatting error. The problem is with SSH itself. It doesn't let us specify a command precisely.
The correct way to pass a command with multiple arguments is as follows: 
Const char str[] = "\"/root/executable arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4\"";
And it worked perfectly.

I found my answer here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80821
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80838

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in QString format, use below format

QString str = QString("%1 %2 %3 %4 %5").arg("/root/executable", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3","arg4");

rc = channel_request_exec(channel, str);

Comment: The declaration is as Channel_request_exec(ssh channel, const char* cmd); so I called channel_request_exec(channel, str.toStdString().c_str); but still argument count shown is 1. I m missing something in formation of Command String ?

Comment: @AnuragSingh, yes but QString does not take care of blank spaces by default.

Comment: I have corrected command string format to the best of my knowledge but still all the arguments are not passed. Only 1 argument i.e. exe path is passed.